# Shatter resistant tea carafe/pitcher/pot

Tags: tea, pot

First let me explain how I make tea.

In the morning I take a pot of boiling water and pour it into a carafe.
I let the the water sit for a minute. I then pour the tea into an old pot from a coffee maker, put the tea bags in the original carafe and pour the water over the tea, let steep.
Pour into another large pot to dilute with water. Over the day I either nuke the tea or I pour it over ice when I want some.

For more then ten years  I had a nice pitcher ( from Ikea ) for this.till one morning it shattered. Now a second pitcher shattered after about two months.

So I need another pot.  I would prefer for obvious reasons that it did not shatter. I do not want to use a stainless steel pot because I notice stainless steel leaves  a taste when I boil water in it. The initial amount of tea I make is approximately one quart, and I have not found a measuring cup that large.

Can anyone make a  suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

Heat-resistant glass is called for, which will be much better suited to withstand the thermal shock of boiling water than regular glass.

I'd use a Pyrex measuring cup -- which are available in one quart (4 cup) sizes, my mother owns one. (I generally just stick with two 2 cups if I need that much liquid, but that won't work for your tea steeping process.) This may require hunting through a few stores (large places dedicated to kitchen goods generally have them) or [buying online](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0000CFMZP). I even [found a *2 quart* measuring cup on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002KZMCY), which I've *never* seen in a store.

You could also get a second old coffee pot, which is similarly designed to cope with hot liquid, or do the steeping in your existing old coffee pot before diluting.

Comment: You can buy a 2qt measuring cup at Walmart. At least here. Though not Pyrex.

Answer (score 1):

Another option (though probably more expensive than Erica's suggestion) is Corningware Pyroceram. It's a glass-ceramic, so it shouldn't absorb any odors. Originally all Corningware cookware was made of this material, but now its only some of their stuff.

You can easily get these in 1.5 quart and larger sizes.

Pyroceram can actually be used on a burner or under the broiler. It's incredibly shatter resistant (supposedly, you can freeze it then hit it with a blow torch, to no ill effect), and actually pretty good even if you drop it.

Answer (score 1):

**Thermal shock** is what is breaking your carafes. Simply stated, you're heating them up too rapidly and unevenly.

While it's true a nice heat-resistant carafe is probably your best solution, you can also try **heating up your glass carafe** with hot tap water before pouring in your boiling water to temper the rapid increase in temperature.

Pour in hot water to the top to get it evenly heated and let it sit for perhaps a minute, pour it out, then do your tea thing. This isn't a guarantee to prevent breakage, but gradually warming it like this will certainly reduce the likelihood.

I use this trick with my French press beakers, which are thin and love to break easily.

Here is a very readable [explanation](http://www.quora.com/Why-does-hot-glass-break-when-it-comes-in-contact-with-cold-water) of why glass breaks under thermal shock. The example is the opposite of your hot-water-in-cold-glass, but still applies in reverse:

> So in our hot-glass-in-ice-water example, the surface is trying to shrink but can't, meaning it is suddenly under tension. And the core is put into compression by resisting the shrinkage. It's not hard to figure out which section of glass wins the tug-of-war -- the surface fails first. And a crack grows out of some microscopic scratch or flaw, growing and spreading until the stress is sufficiently relieved or the glass is broken clean through.